# Cordova 5.0.0 in Visual 2015 - white screen in Android app

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I've created sample application from Ionic Tabs App template and immediately changed configuration to use Cordova CLI 5.0.0 (instead of default 4.3.0). Also set Android Minimum SDK Version to 21, and Target SDK Version to 22.

I've built the APK in Debug mode and on my HTC One I've got only white screen and nothing else.

Running on Ripple - Nexus works OK. The same application using default Cordova 4.3.0 works OK on phone.

The same effect is with JDK 1.7.0_79 and JDK 1.8.0_45.

Is there any known problems with Cordova CLI 5.0.0? How should I proceed?

Comment: did u see the splash screen?  if there's only 'hello world' in the index.html, can u see the hello world?  here 'hello world' means without any plugin.  if it's too troublesome to do that simply create a new project and test it.  May not all plugins compatible to all version of cordova.

Comment: Could you try removing and re-adding the Android platform (cordova platform remove android && cordova platform add android)? We published a list of known issues between VS and Cordova 5.0.0 (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/cordova-known-issues-vs.aspx) which may also be helpful. Let me know!

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I will try your suggestions in a couple of days and will report back.

Comment: @KennethLi No splash screen. There are no plugins used. I've tested `Blank App (Apache Cordova)` template and it works OK with cordova 5.0.0. Its basic `Hello, your application is ready!` index.html is also working when used in Ionic Tabs App, so it must be something wrong with Ionic framework. Is there a way to debug the app on device?

Comment: @JonathanCarter It doesn't change anything. See also my previous comment.

Comment: you can de-bug the app using Chrome Device debugging... 
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You should install "Whitelist" plugin.